# Applications Folder

Tags: nautilus, directory, appmenu

I moved my applications folder into the Home folder without thinking and now I am unable to move them back into the usr folder.

I want to move the applications folder back to where it was. How would I do this?

Comment: Well, how did you move it to your Home folder (step by step)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tricky because I'm not sure whether you mean the /home folder or your own user folder (which is located at /home/your-username). So first check to make sure you know where the applications folder really is before you do anything. Also check if the applications folder is the one containing many icons with application names underneath each icon, which the following two commands assume that it is.

If the applications folder is currently in your own user folder, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo mv ~/applications/ /usr/share/
```

If the applications folder is currently in the /home folder, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo mv /home/applications/ /usr/share/
```